# JavaScript function printing itself rather than returning value

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to return a Boolean value based on truthy of a given condition from an arrow function. The code is look like following

```
checkIsBasicInformationCompleted() {
 const info = this.basicInformation;
 const valid = () => {return !!(info.firstName && info.lastName && info.email && info.phone);};
 console.log(valid);
},
```

But here instead of returning `true/false`, this function is printing itself. Can anybody explain the thing running here ? And how can I get a `true/false` value here ?

Fiddle sample: https://jsfiddle.net/tebz4Lc3/

Comment: You're never *calling* your arrow function… Why's it a function in the first place instead of a simple expression?

Comment: `valid` is a function. To get the result of it, call it: `valid()`

Answer (score 1):

You are printing a reference to the function here, use `console.log( valid() )` to actually execute the function and print the return value.

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(valid());
```

This is how the logging should be.